# Design different when opening website via URL compared to opening HTML file on browser

Tags: html, css

When I open my HTML file on Chrome, the HTML and CSS are shown properly. However, after I uploaded it on a server and when i open the website from the URL, it is being displayed all wrong. What is the reasoning behind this? I used the code given by Mailchimp for the newsletter html and then modified the design.

HTML:

```
<!-- NEWSLETTER START-->


        <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
        <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style type="text/css">
            /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
               We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
        </style>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup">
        <form action="https://whammychat.us18.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=87245bd3ecc92795b3acf19b0&amp;id=5d33f134e3" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
            <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
            <h2>What to Stay Updated?</h2>
            <p class="description2">We hired a team of Koalas to write our newsletters. <br> They sleep 18 hours a day so, don't worry about spam! </p>
                            <p class="description2"> We just want to inform you when Whammychat is available and any other crazy things our team is up to.</p>
        <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
        <br>

        <div class="mc-field-group">
            <label for="mce-EMAIL" id="emailadd">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="personalinfo">
        </div>

        <div class="mc-field-group">
            <label for="mce-FNAME" id="firstname">First Name </label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="personalinfo">
        </div>

            <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
            </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_87245bd3ecc92795b3acf19b0_5d33f134e3" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>

                <br>

                <p class="policy"><br><br>By clicking on Subscribe, you automatically agree to our newsletter policies.<p>
                <br>
                <input type="image" name="submit" class="submit" src="Subscribe%20Button.png" border="0" value="Subscribe" alt="Submit">

            </div>

        </form>
        </div>
```

```
        <!-- NEWSLETTER END-->
```

CSS:

```
/* NEWSLETTER*/
form div input {
    font-family: Helvetica;
}


label {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;

}

#personalinfo {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 15vw;
    height: 2.5vw;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    border: solid #3fa6d2;
    border-radius: 4px;

}


@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {

    .description2 {
        font-size: 1.8vw;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }

    #personalinfo {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 15vw;
    height: 2.5vw;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    border: solid #3fa6d2;
    border-radius: 4px;

 }

    #firstname {
        font-size: 1.8vw;
   }

   #emailadd {
        font-size: 1.8vw;
   }

   .indicates-required{
        font-size:1.5vw
   }

   .policy {
        font-size: 1.5vw;
        margin: 10% 10% -1% 10%;
        font-family: Helvetica;
   }



   .submit {
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: -9%;
    margin-bottom: -7%;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {

    .description2 {
        font-size: 90%;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }

    #personalinfo {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
        height: 20px;
        margin-top: 2%;
        margin-left: 3%;
        border: solid #3fa6d2;
        border-radius: 4px;

    }


   .indicates-required{
        font-size: 80%;
        margin-top: 5%;
        margin-bottom: -2%;
        font-family: Helvetica;
   }

   .policy {
        font-size: 80%;
        margin: 10% 10% -1% 10%;
   }

   .submit {
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: -9%;
    margin-bottom: -7%;

    }

}

    .mc-field-group label {
        font-size: 1.8vw;
        margin-top: 2%;
        font-family: Helvetica;
    }

/* Style the input elements and the submit button */


.submit {
    transition: 1s ease;
}

.submit:focus {
    outline:0;
}

.submit:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: 0.5s ease;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried emptying your Cache?

Comment: try inspect element do you see any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all servers were created equal.

It's possible that some images or CSS files were not loaded because the server blocked them. This is often related to headers sent from the server's response which browsers usually respect and block.

For example, the server could return this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.only-my-domain.com
```

which means that the domain your site is being served from does not allow loading javascript and css files from domains other then the ones specified in the header.

Missing fonts or other assets could also be the problem.
Check the browser's console and network tabs for errors and warning.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was the CSS styling link the HTML I had.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a scheme-relative URL: `link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css"`

If you open a page containing this from the file system, the scheme is `file://`. I'm guessing you don't have a drive or network location such that `"file://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css"` resolves correctly.

Add `http:` or `https:` to the beginning of that URL if you want it to resolve while browsing from the file system.

[@Shahar's answer is also relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51727305). CORS is likely a problem with some of the links you're using as well.